# how to find Action is exist in controller in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to check for example `deleteAction` exist in `TimeController` from other controller

how to check this?

Comment: simple and quick: ``method_exists(TimeController::class, 'deleteAction')``

Comment: Heh nice Michael we had the exact same idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is so broad and without context I'll answer using general PHP:

```
if (method_exists(TimeController:class, 'deleteAction')) {
    // method exists, do something here
}
```

If you want to check if a particular route name exists, that's a little different.

Comment: It's basic PHP, so it's not different in using the PHP-framework Symfony ;-)